# Migrate a Magento 1.X module to 2.0

Tags: magento, module, migration, magento2

We're developing a module for Magento 1.9 and want to support Magento 2.0 quickly after that.
I discovered https://github.com/magento/code-migration and wondered if anyone had experience with it?

Should we expect a full rewrite of the module to support that 2.0? Does anybody have experience in that task?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently trying to migrate my module for Magento 1.x to support 2.0, and done some research in this area. However, my code-migration isn't completed yet.

As I know, after we use this tool to convert the structure and code, we still require to test and modify the module. The toolkit is a tool to simplify our process, not helping us to create a 100%-fit module to the Magento 2.0 version.

You may refer to the following video for further explanation by the toolkit developer team:

[Imagine 2016 - Developer Deep Dive: Magento 1.x to Magento 2 Code Migration Tool](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lXJ6rMdQvkk)

Hope this helps!